# Failure/Error: $driver.navigate.to ENV['URL'] in ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, environment-variables

While running the test case in the terminal with headless = true. I am getting the below error message.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm7oe.png)

Please find the details below:

I am using chromedriver version 86 with chrome browswer version 86 and same has been updated in .env file.
Also, I am running the scripts with Ubuntu in windows.

Answer (score 0):

The error, `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` means that the URL could not be resolved into an IP address. Most likely, `ENV['URL']` is not returning a valid URL, there is a typo in the hostname, or it is referencing a private host that the script's DNS cannot resolve. Consider temporarily adding some debugging information, such as

```
url = ENV['URL']
STDERR.puts "Navigating to [#{url}]"
$driver.navigate.to url
```

or using [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) to pause your code, and check to make sure things are as you expect:

```
require 'pry'; binding.pry
$driver.navigate.to ENV['URL']
```

From the Pry shell, you can see what `ENV['URL']` evaluates to, and also manually drive the `$driver` to see if it works as you expect.

If the URL in fact seems correct, then the issue is likely related to a private host and DNS issue. Ensure you can navigate to the url by other means on that same server (if it's a server, consider trying to `ping` the hostname, or use `curl` or `wget` for a quick check).

Comment: Yes, I am able to navigate to the URL by using wget. Also, I am getting the timeout error now as mentioned below. 

Failure/Error: $wait.until { $driver.current_url == ENV['URL'] + '/projects' }

     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeoutError:
       timed out after 10 seconds

I am using ubuntu shell in windows to run the ruby scripts.